# Adding values of a pandas column only at specific indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working on pandas data frame, something like below:

```
   id        vals
0   1          11
1   1         5.5
2   1          -2
3   1           8
4   2           3
5   2           4
6   2          19
7   2          20
```

Above is just a small part of the df, the **vals** are grouped by **id** , and there will always be equal number of vals per id. In above case it's 4 and 4 values for id = 1 and id =2.

What I am trying to achieve is to add the value at index 0 with value at index 4, then value at index 1 with value at index 5 and so on. 
Following is the expected df/ series, say df2:

```
    total
0      14
1     9.5
2      17
3      28
```

Real df has hundreds of id and not just two as above.
**Groupby()** can be used but I dont get how to get the specific indices from each group.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` on modulo of `df.index` values and take `sum` of `vals`

```
In [805]: df.groupby(df.index % 4).vals.sum()
Out[805]:
0    14.0
1     9.5
2    17.0
3    28.0
Name: vals, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are exactly `4` values per ID, we can simply reshape the underlying `1D` array data to `2D` array and sum along the appropriate axis (axis=0 in this case) -

```
pd.DataFrame({'total':df.vals.values.reshape(-1,4).sum(0)})
```

Sample run -

```
In [192]: df
Out[192]: 
   id  vals
0   1  11.0
1   1   5.5
2   1  -2.0
3   1   8.0
4   2   3.0
5   2   4.0
6   2  19.0
7   2  20.0

In [193]: pd.DataFrame({'total':df.vals.values.reshape(-1,4).sum(0)})
Out[193]: 
   total
0   14.0
1    9.5
2   17.0
3   28.0
```